# Is there a way to evaluate a literal string to quoted string in VIm?

Tags: escaping, vim, string-literals, quote

That is, I want to build a quoted string on the fly that contains escape sequences (more preciously, escape characters)

Here is my code:

```
let s:char = "x"
let s:combo = "\\<C-" . s:char . ">"
```

Now `s:combo` contains `"\\<C-x>"`, how can I eval it to `"\<C-x>"` to perform a combo with `:normal`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `:h eval()`. Something like:

```
let s:char = "x"
let s:combo = eval('"\<C-' . s:char . '>"')
```

Note the double quotes inside the single quotes.

Comment: It works, thank you! Very clever. I tried eval("\\<c-x>") but it wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do what you want is using 'exe':

```
exe "normal \<c-x>"
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did, but I want to eval "\\<c-x>" to "\<c-x>" because it was built on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what is control sequence you can use the following instead:

```
let s:char='x'
let s:combo=nr2char(char2nr(toupper(s:char))-0x40)
```

. This will work for every single latin letter character.

By the way, in your example `s:combo` contains `\<C-x>`, not `\\<C-x>`. The problem is that `:normal` expects control character, not `\<C-x>`, `\<C-x>` in *double quotes* is translated to it.